# Hashing line segments

Tags: hashtable

I have a number of line segments given their endpoints. i need to use hashing to store the line segments one by one in a suitable data structure T. While generating, the two endpoints of each segment should be randomly selected and a newly generated segment should be inserted in T only if it is not already there in T.

Can someone suggest a suitable hashing function by which i can store the endpoints of the line segments uniquely.

Comment: Unless the order of the endpoints is significant, make sure your hashing function orders the points in a consistent (deterministic) way before hashing.  Otherwise X, Y may not hash to the same value as Y, X.  Alternatively, you can use a function that is order-independent ( e.g. (x1+y1)*A + (x2+y2)*B )

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to just use a multiplier and addition.

```
hash = 2011 * x + y;
```

The benefit of it is that it is very fast to calculate. Other solutions could be to use more complicated iterations over the digits, say similar to the Java string hashing algorithm

```
for(int i = 0; i < n_digits; i++){
    hash = hash * 31 + x_y_digit[i];
}
```